# How to test/rewrite the label-enable functions?

Tags: go

I have a code that uses labels and doesn't separate logic and view (dialog-based). There are bugs and aren't any line of unittests =(

```
func UiNetworks(ui *gui.DialogUi, data *xmlinput.XMLInputData, allowedNics host.NICList, gconf *guest.Config) error {
    guestPciSlotCounter := data.GuestNic.PCI.FirstSlot
    lastGuestPciSlotCounter := guestPciSlotCounter
    portCounter := 1
    lastPortCounter := portCounter
    i := 0

MainLoop:
    for i < len(data.Networks.Configs) {
        net := data.Networks.Configs[i]
    PolicyLoop:
        for {
            var modes []xmlinput.ConnectionMode

            if net.UiModeBinding == nil || len(net.UiModeBinding) == 0 {
                for _, mode := range net.Modes {
                    modes = append(modes, mode.Type)
                }
            } else {
                var err error
                modes, err = uiNetworkPolicySelector(ui, net)
                if err != nil {
                    switch err.Error() {
                    case gui.DialogMoveBack:
                        gconf.Networks = gconf.Networks[:i]
                        gconf.NICLists = gconf.NICLists[:i]
                        portCounter = lastPortCounter - 1
                        guestPciSlotCounter = lastGuestPciSlotCounter - 1
                        if i == 0 {
                            return err
                        }
                        i--
                        continue MainLoop
                    case gui.DialogNext:
                        i++
                        continue MainLoop
                    case gui.DialogExit:
                        os.Exit(1)
                    default:
                        return err
                    }

                }
            }

            retainedNics, err := host_hwfilter.NicsByType(allowedNics, modes)
            if err != nil {
                return utils.FormatError(err)
            }
            if len(retainedNics) == 0 {
                ui.Output(gui.Warning, "No interfaces have been found.", "Press <OK> to return to menu.")
                continue MainLoop
            }
            if net.UiResetCounter {
                portCounter = 1
            }
            list, err := uiNicSelectMenu(ui, data, &portCounter, &guestPciSlotCounter, retainedNics, net, i)
            if err != nil {
                switch err.Error() {
                case gui.DialogMoveBack:
                    if i == 0 {
                        return err
                    }
                    gconf.Networks = gconf.Networks[:i]
                    gconf.NICLists = gconf.NICLists[:i]
                    continue PolicyLoop
                case gui.DialogExit:
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
            }

            gconf.Networks = append(gconf.Networks, net)
            gconf.NICLists = append(gconf.NICLists, list)
            lastPortCounter = portCounter
            lastGuestPciSlotCounter = guestPciSlotCounter
            i++
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

How I can test it? Or rewrite it?

Regards.

Comment: Use of labels appear to be pretty standard. `PolicyLoop` is being used only for the sake of readability. Tests shouldn't require any special treatment as long as you are interested in testing function behavior, which should not depend on the function internals to begin with..

Comment: Please provide any example how to test the above functions.